# how to remove the popup notification of keyring login?

Tags: kali-linux, password, notifications

Whenever I visit any Index page of any website, it pops up with this notification.

[image]

I'm using Kali GNU/Linux Rolling.

Comment: This is a `gnome-keyring` issue, it has nothing to do with Kali Linux. What you need to do is look up how to disable or remove `gnome-keyring` on google  if it is bothering you and you can then find a solution to your issue.

Comment: apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net 7D8D0BF6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your browser is Google Chrome, you may get rid of gnome-keyring in it. 
Just switch to internal Chrome password storage with **--password-store=basic** on Google Chrome start:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic
```